# MS Access 2016 Enable "Edit Hyperlink..." command in custom shortcut menu for .accde file

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, rdbms, ms-access-2016

As a caveat to this question I am a beginner Access 2016 programmer of 2 months, but believe I have some intermediate to *relatively* advanced knowledge of the software as it's just about all I've been doing at work the last two months. I also realize now that I'm asking for trouble using hyperlinked fields as most people believe they're more hassle than they're worth (at least in older Access versions, it's surprisingly a little difficult to find Access 2016 information and opinions in 2018.. at least for me cause I'm apparently incapable of using "the google machine" properly), but I'm in a little too deep now.

At the moment I am trying to deploy a new database system but have run into some issues when testing. After turning my .accdb file into a .accde file the command to "Edit Hyperlink..." vanishes entirely from the shortcut menu when right-clicking. My employer would really like this functionality to be present in the final product, as he wants to display the file name but link to the file location in a shared network drive. I also need document control at his small company to be able to edit the hyperlinks but don't want them using an .accdb file that they could inadvertently make design changes to, or god knows what.

I have attempted to make a custom shortcut menu using this VBA module, which is executed by an AutoExec Macro, running upon opening the database.

```
Public Function CreateCustomRightClickMenu()

Const msoBarPopup As Long = 5, msoControlButton As Long = 1

' Create a shortcut menu named "CustomRightClickMenu"
With Application.CommandBars
    With .Add(name:="CustomRightClickMenu", Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
    ' Add cut command
        .Controls.Add type:=msoControlButton, id:=21
    ' Add copy command
        .Controls.Add type:=msoControlButton, id:=19
    ' Add paste command
        .Controls.Add type:=msoControlButton, id:=22
    ' Add hyperlink command.
        .Controls.Add type:=msoControlButton, id:=1576
    ' Add edit hyperlink command.
        .Controls.Add type:=msoControlButton, id:=1577
    End With
End With

End Function
```

I can get this function to work just fine in the .accde file, but the "Edit Hyperlink..." command is still unusable - it's greyed out. **Is there some way to override this?**

The only information I could find as to *why* this is the case is because a compiled .accde file restricts all design tools. I thought this explanation was rather... lackluster.  Editing hyperlinks constitutes as a design tool? How would a hyperlinked field ever be advantageous then, in an automated system? And by automated I mean one that can run freely without a DBA sitting in some back-end file all day and updating the file's address lying beneath the display text. I will be on the opposite end of the country in a month and a half and will not be able to *dip my toes* in the back-end anymore so to speak.

Additionally, I saw many solutions for this problem in earlier versions of Access, but not in 2016. **So my question is, what is it about the 2016 version in particular that is making this so difficult?
Or, can this be done at all?**

Alternatively I've thought about using attachments and was assured that they don't bloat your system because Access will compress the files. After testing this I'm relatively sure it's not the case. I attached one 900kb .pdf file to 3 separate records in a database copy, and the .accdb file's size increased ~2700kb, as is to be expected. Compact and Repair had no effect on the final file size (3,974kb). 900kb files weren't realistic for my system though, and if my math is correct I should be able to store about 11,000-13,000 records in a 2GB Access database if I have 3 50kb files per record, subtracting 1000-2000 to account for the space of my access objects. Is this a realistic calculation, and what problems will I run into if I try and go this route?

EDIT: After briefly glancing over this webpage yesterday:

https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-hyperlink-data-type

I thought about it some more and realized I could just have our Doc control enter hyperlinks in the format "DisplayText#FileFullPathway#" ignoring sub address and scroll tip text.

And so far so good.

Then something interesting happened. I sent out a beta .accde file for DC to play with today, and the Edit Hyperlink... tool was magically available when I was getting her to test something unrelated (yesterday on her same machine the command either wouldn't be there, or if I had the CustomMenu set-up then the command was greyed out). I had deleted my custom menu from the entire database, no VBA module exists for anything menu related and the form's ShortcutMenu property is now blank. You'd think I'd be relieved but this is bothering me even more now - if I didn't enable it who did, and how come it wasn't there yesterday prior to having wasted all this time coming up with a workaround? Maybe I'm supposed to have that menu command and it was just bugged yesterday, but my travels through the Googlesphere yesterday suggest otherwise. This is driving me bonkers. For now my problem is resolved but I'd still like to know what's happening here.